# How to load jquery before all other javascript with master template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a master template which roughly looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        // load css files
    </head>
    <body> 
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        // load js files including jquery 
    </body>
</html>
```

Now all other sites for my app look like this

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block body %}  
    // site content
{% endblock %}
```

for each site I have some specific `javascript` code, which I put at the end of the body block. But this means that this `javascript` is loaded before `jquery` is loaded (which is done in the master template). Since some of the `javascript` in the body tag requires `jquery` (like e.g. the `$(document).read() function)` I get errors. The simple solution is to include `jquery` in each body tag separately... however, that starts to undermine the point of the master template... is there any better solution?
thanks 
carl

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to say that my current solution is to load jquery before the body, however, google pagespeed complains about this so I was looking for a better solution

Comment: are you using django ?

Comment: Why on earth was this post edited to make `javascript` and `jquery` monospace?  Those are names, not code.

Comment: And to answer the question, you could put the jQuery reference inside your head tag.  This will ensure that it's loaded and evaluated before all the scripts in the body are, at the expense of a minor delay to the initial page render.

Comment: @IanL it does't mean that it is a code. I highlighted it for more readable look. And to your comment, it is a bad practice to put scripts in the head tag

Comment: sorry I added this point to my question above... I currently do load jquery before the body... but I was looking for a solution which loads jquery with all other js after the body...

Answer (score 0):

If you have scripts in `{% block body %}` of extended files that dependens on **jQuery**; if so , it is recommended to load jQuery on `head` of`master.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        // load css files
        //load jQuery --------------!!!!!!
    </head>
    <body> 
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        // load js files excluding jquery 
    </body>
</html>
```